# join () function if data entered

Tags: php, forms

I have a jQuery mobile form with the data posting to a review.php form. When there is no data entered in an array of check boxs (no data needed from user) the review returns

*Warning: join() [function.join]: Invalid arguments passed in /hermes/waloraweb076/b2830/moo.revolveis/hg/order/review.php on line 35*

Here is a sample of the form:

```
<li data-role="fieldcontain">
                      <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                          <legend>Choose Grind:</legend>
                          <input type="checkbox" name="grind51[vgrind]" id="vgrind" class="custom" value="V-Grind">
                          <label for="vgrind">V-Grind</label>
                          <input type="checkbox" name="grind51[tourgrind]" id="tourgrind" class="custom" value="Tour-Grind">
                          <label for="tourgrind">Tour Grind</label>
                          <input type="checkbox" name="grind51[healgrind]" id="healgrind" class="custom" value="Heal-Grind">
                          <label for="healgrind">Heal Grind</label>
                          <input type="checkbox" name="grind51[nogrind]" id="nogrind" class="custom" value="No Grind">
                          <label for="nogrind">No Grind</label>
                      </fieldset>
</li>
```

Here is a sample of the review.php:

```
<?php

    $grind51 = join(", ", $_REQUEST["grind51"]);
     echo (!empty($_REQUEST['grind51'])) ? "<div class='reviewItem'><span class='reviewTitle'>51 Grind:</span>{$grind51}</div>" : "";

?>
```

When there is data entered for the array if returns the information fine. Is there a way to not get an error if no information is entered? By the way, line 35 pertains to

```
$grind51 = join(", ", $_REQUEST["grind51"]);
```

in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check whether `$_REQUEST['grind51']` is set before you try to `join` it. The error is caused be the fact that an empty return isn't an array (and can't be joined).

Comment: How would I go about checking it is set? I am still pretty basic at PHP. Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP looks good, the HTML I would change: set the element names to just `name[]` in order to populate a regular (not associative) array.

```
<li data-role="fieldcontain">
                      <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                          <legend>Choose Grind:</legend>
                          <input type="checkbox" name="grind51[]" id="vgrind" class="custom" value="V-Grind">
                          <label for="vgrind">V-Grind</label>
                          <input type="checkbox" name="grind51[]" id="tourgrind" class="custom" value="Tour-Grind">
                          <label for="tourgrind">Tour Grind</label>
                          <input type="checkbox" name="grind51[]" id="healgrind" class="custom" value="Heal-Grind">
                          <label for="healgrind">Heal Grind</label>
                          <input type="checkbox" name="grind51[]" id="nogrind" class="custom" value="No Grind">
                          <label for="nogrind">No Grind</label>
                      </fieldset>
</li>
```

Do some quick error checking in PHP to be sure you have data in an array passed in:

```
if ( isset( $_REQUEST['grind51'] ) && is_array( $_REQUEST['grind51'] ) ) { 
     $grind51 = join(", ", $_REQUEST["grind51"]);
}
```